# Let $ABCD$ be a rhombus

Tags: geometry

Let  $ABCD$ be  a  rhombus and  $E$  and $F$ be  the  middle of the  sides  $AB$  and $BC$.  If  $P$  is  a point  in  the  interior   of  the  rhombus  such   that  $PE = CE$ and $ AP = AF$  then  $B, P, D $ are collinear points. I  have  no  idea. I  tried using coordinates. I  think is  necessary a construction.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ has the same distance from $A$ and $F$ thus it lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AF$ and for similar reason lies on the perp bisector of $CE$.

It follows that $P$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ which contains both $B$ and $D$ so $B,P,D$ are collinear.

*QED*

*Edit*

It cannot be that $PF=AF$ and $B,P,D$ are collinear. Look at the second picture. The red circle is the locus of the point $P$ having distance $AF$ from $A$, the circle with centre $A$ and radius $AF$. As $P$ must be on the perpendicular bisector of the segment $CE$ it follows that line $BD$ does not contain $P$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why  $PA= PF$? It  is  obviously?

Comment: @PregatireMatematica it is written in the hypothesis $AP = AF$

Comment: Yes,  But  you  said  that $AP = PF$

Comment: @PregatireMatematica Please, read my edit at the bottom of my answer...

Answer (score -1):

The hint.

Use  reflection $S$ of the rhombus in the line $BD$.

Thus, $S(P)=P$.

Comment: I  don't  understand...

Comment: @Pregatire Matematica Since $ABCD$ is a rhombus, we have $S(ABCD)=CBAD$, $S(F)=E$, $S(E)=F$,  S(perpendicular bisector of AF)=perpendicular bisector of CE and S(perpendicular bisector of CE)=perpendicular bisector of AF. Now, since perpendicular bisector of AF intersects  perpendicular bisector of CE in the point $P$, we get $S(P)=P$ and since only point $X$ for which $S(X)=X$ are points which placed on the line $BD$, we obtain $P\in BD$.